# Is there a way with gawk5 to launch shell commands in parallel?

Tags: awk

Using gawk 5, we are able to launch shell commands with something like:

```
command = "echo toto"
command | getline
```

However, this hangs until the command is complete, for example:

```
BEGIN {
    command = "{ echo start >> test.log ; sleep 10 ; echo stop >> test.log ;}"
    command | getline
    print "terminated"
}
```

I tried using a `&` at the end of the command, without success:

```
BEGIN {
    command = "{ echo start >> test.log ; sleep 10 ; echo stop >> test.log ;} &"
    command | getline
    print "terminated"
}
```

I would like to be able to launch shell commands as new processes and "forget" about them. For example:

```
BEGIN {
    command1 = "dosomething.sh &"
    command1 | getline
    command2 = "dosomething2.sh &"
    command2 | getline
    print "terminated"
}
```

Can this be achieved using gawk 5 **only** ?

Comment: Maybe pipe the output from `awk` into `bash`?

Comment: awk is a tool to manipulate text. shell is a tool to manipulate files/processes and sequence calls to commands. You're asking how to use awk as if it was a shell - don't do that. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to call `getline` safely but again - don't do what you're trying to do as it's a job for shell, not awk. You're doing `shell { awk { subshell { cmd } } }` when you should be doing `shell { cmd }` or MAYBE `shell { awk; cmd }`.

Comment: @EdMorton I am aware of that :) . I did not give the full context for clarity but the awk is supposed to call other awk programs. It is, as you said, not how it's supposed to work, but my requirement is "much awk as possible and if possible nothing more".

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{ system("echo foo") }'` and `echo $(awk 'BEGIN{print "foo"}')` have about as much awk as each other - you don't need to have awk acting as a shell to use as much awk as possible in combination with shell commands. If you want to ask a new question with more of your real problem we can help you do whatever  you're trying to do the right way, if not no worries and all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`| getline` waits for something to read. So output something so it can read it.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { cmd="{ echo something; ( echo start >&2 ; sleep 1; echo stop >&2 ) & }"; cmd | getline; print "Awk end"; }' <<<'' ; echo "Awk end"; sleep 2
Awk end
start
After awk
stop
```